# Rails 4.2 :accepts_nested_attributes_for with build_relation, how to select existing OR create new?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Basically, when creating a new Entity, I use build_owner to present the nested attributes for the owner.  However, I want the user to have the option to select an existing owner OR create a new one as part of the form.

Entity Model:

```
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner
end
```

Owner Model (Devise Model, left out validations):

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :entities
end
```

Entities Controller (new method):

```
def new
  @entity = Entity.new
  @entity.build_owner
end
```

Entities View (new method):

```
<%= f.fields_for :owner do |o| %>
  <%= o.select :id, Owner.all, include_blank: 'Create a New Owner' %>
  <%= o.text_field :name %>
  <%= o.email_field :email %>
<% end %>
```

So if the user selects an owner from the list, the application should assign this owner as the owner_id, and ignore the :name and :email fields.  However, currently the application kicks back an error since :name and :email are validated for presence.

How can I allow the user to either select an existing owner or create a new one as part of creating the Entity record?

-- UPDATE

Through the power of JavaScript, I have made this work by giving the :name and :email fields the :disabled prop when the selectbox's val is blank.  However, I'm still interested in a more Rails-y way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding if the owner exists first, then assign it if it does. Otherwise build it. Code is just for guide. It is untested

```
def new
  @entity = Entity.new
  begin
    @owner = Owner.find(params[:owner_id])
    @entity.owner = @owner
  rescue RecordNotFound => e
    @entity.build_owner
  end
end
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid using a param to specify the owner_id, as that means I'll have to provide another form or button to get this to work, which I don't want.